# Js for each key return bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, return

I'm triying to perform a map script in JS, but I got a bug when I try to return my array key value.
This is working from 0 to 9 , when the key is > 10 , the return value will be , '1' and '0' and not '10'.

```
Object.keys(City).forEach(function(key) {
   var idcity = City[key];
   alert(idcity);
});
```

My array value are from a php function and I had echo the array and the key show up is '10' and not '1' '0'.
The problem is from this small JS script maybe..

City :

```
    var City= {
  <?php
  $mycity->CreateMarker($_SESSION['visitorID']);
  ?>
};
// CreateMarker inside
       if($dateformater >= date("Y-m-d")){ 
         echo "{$id}: { 'lat': {$Lat}, 'lon': {$Lon} },";
```

$id is the array key

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the content of `City` ?

Comment: @TGrif Yes , I paste

Comment: Instead of the PHP used to generate `City`, can you show us a sample of what might be returned *after* any server-side processing (eg. copy from Chrome’s *view source*)?

Comment: Instead of creating your own json, create an array in PHP, and use `json_encode` to make a properly formatted json.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to integer

```
Object.keys(City).forEach(function(key) {
var idcity = City[key];
 alert(parseInt(idcity, 10)); });
```